# webpack.ProvidePlugin with zepto

Tags: webpack

I have a project which use zepto in lots of modules.
As you know, webpack.ProvidePlugin is the best way to handle this scenario, with it, I do not need to import zepto in every module manually.

zepto doesn't export itself, so I can not import it with ProvidePlugin.

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'zepto'
    })
  ]
```

I know there is a zepto wrap called [webpack-zepto](https://github.com/RexMorgan/webpack-zepto).

But if I adopt this solution, every time when zepto update, I need to update the code myself.

Is there a method to solve my issue?

Answer (score 4):

You can try `script-loader`:

```
webpack.config.js

loaders: [
    {
        test: require.resolve('zepto/zepto.min.js'),
        loader: 'script'
    }
]
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'zepto/zepto.min.js'
    })
]
```

It will read the `zepto.min.js` file and execute it, just as you put it in a script tag, then in your module, you can access zepto by `window.$`

UPDATE:

If you simply want to use `$` instead of `window.$`, you can require zepto.min.js file through `exports-loader` and `script-loader`:

```
webpack.config.js

loaders: [
    {
        test: require.resolve('zepto/zepto.min.js'),
        loader: 'exports?window.$!script'
    }
]
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'zepto/zepto.min.js'
    })
]
```